# How to use/parse data just submitted by an Apex Form?

Tags: oracle-apex

I am new to Apex so apologies if this is a really obvious question.

I have a report and form working where a user can fill in a bunch of data and then submit it to the database. How would I go around retrieving that inputted data, parse it, manipulate it and then give a text report back to the user? Note that for specific reasons I cannot have a trigger on the database to fire whenever it gets updated.

Comment: What do you mean by "a text report"?  Do you mean a file, or just show some text on the screen?

Comment: Preferably both.

Comment: What do you mean by "How would I go around retrieving that inputted data, parse it, manipulate it and then give a text report back to the user"? Please explain this in more detail.

Comment: Example: As soon as I hit submit I want to be able to run some javascript or the like to produce an output with a mix of static and variable content that uses some of the submitted data as variables.